# R question, how to plot a histgram when the given data is range?

Tags: r

[image]

I know how to plot the data if the data is given one to one, but I am wondering how to plot a histogram of it if the data is given in a range

Comment: In that case simply make a bar chart.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach as mentioned by **@stefan** using `geom_bar()` as you have the values summarised. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Class.limits=c('90-98','99-107','108-116','117-125','126-134'),
                 Frequency=c(6,22,43,28,9),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
df %>% mutate(Class.limits=factor(Class.limits,levels = unique(Class.limits),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Class.limits,y=Frequency))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',fill='red',alpha=0.5)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))
```

Output:

[image]